# Что такое заголовки HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER?

Tags: apache, http

Как он передается?

При проксировании сайта хочу скрыть данный заголовок. Через директиву `mod_headers` в apache подменил все заголовки сайта с которого проксил, но этот данная директива не поменяла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за заголовок такой, и как с ним можно работать. Я ранее думал, что все данные, кроме ip, передаются через http заголовки, но получается нет.

Answer (score 1):

Это Reverse Proxy Request Header, а именно это hostname of the proxy server.Т.е данный заголовок будет ставится прокси сервером.Либо настройки прокси сервера, либо headers unset apache.